# Deselect Select All checkbox after DML from apex class

Tags: apex, javascript, salesforce-id

I have below code snippet where I have perfectly working select all checkbox. My requirement is to deselect the checkbox after I have successfully updated relevant records in apex class.

**Page**

```
<apex:pageblockTable id="XYZ" value="{!wrapList}" var="itr" >
                            <apex:column >
                                <apex:facet name="header">
                                    <apex:inputCheckbox onclick="selectAllCheckboxes(this,'inputId')"/>
                                </apex:facet>
                                <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!itr.selected}" id="inputId"/>
                            </apex:column>......
```

**Select All function**

```
 function selectAllCheckboxes(obj,receivedInputID){
            var inputCheckBox = document.getElementsByTagName("input");                  
            for(var i=0; i<inputCheckBox.length; i++){          
                if(inputCheckBox[i].id.indexOf(receivedInputID)!=-1){                                     
                    inputCheckBox[i].checked = obj.checked;
                }
            }
       }
```

I need to deselect obj.checked = false only after DML update done and Success pagemessage shows on Page.

Can someone please help me here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to bind it to something:

```
public Boolean isSelectAllChecked { get; set; }
```

...

```
<apex:inputCheckbox value="{!isSelectAllChecked}" onclick="selectAllCheckboxes(this,'inputId')"/>
```

From there, you can toggle it as you like in Apex code.